# Validation Not Working When Checking If ImageButton Is Empty

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Using Kotlin in Android Studio, I created a form where user can fill in necessary details AND click an imageButton to launch the camera, take picture and submit the form. I want to add a validation where the user is prevented from submitting the form if they did not take a photo.

I have tried to validate by using `imageButton.drawable == null` but it did not display the error toast.

Here are the relevant parts of my codes:

```
class FormActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var selectedPhotoUri : Uri? = null

    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA = 1001
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_artactivity)

        ...

        val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)

        // launch camera
        imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            takePhotoUsingCamera()
        }

        val submitButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submitButton)

        submitButton.setOnClickListener {
            submitForm(userId.toString(), HRWAnswer, ResultAnswer)
        }
    }

    private fun takePhotoUsingCamera(){
        ImagePicker.with(this).cameraOnly()
            .crop()
            .start(REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA)
    }

    // to access the image captured
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode){
                REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA -> {
                    selectedPhotoUri = data!!.data
                    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
                    val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)

                    val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
                    imageButton.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun submitForm(userId : String, TestOption: String, ResultOption: String){

        ...

        val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)

        if (imageButton.drawable == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image of your Test result is required!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            imageButton.requestFocus()
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're still working with the same setup, your `ImageButton` has a drawable set in the layout – `app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_camera_capture"` – so it's not going to be null unless you set it to null somewhere in the code.

Comment: Using the UI component to store your data, especially something as large as a photo, is very fragile. And if the user rotates their screen, the photo will be lost. I would be immediately putting that photo reference in a ViewModel property to preserve it if there's a configuration change. And you can check that property for being null instead of the UI component.

Answer (score 0):

Check this may it helps you.

```
class FormActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     lateinit var imageButton : ImageButton//HERE YOU NEED TO ADD BUTTON.Dont add buttons initialization multiple time in once class.
        var selectedPhotoUri : Uri? = null
    
        companion object {
            const val REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA = 1001
        }
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_artactivity)
    
            ...
    
            imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
    
            // launch camera
            imageButton.setOnClickListener {
                takePhotoUsingCamera()
            }
    
            val submitButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submitButton)
    
            submitButton.setOnClickListener {
                submitForm(userId.toString(), HRWAnswer, ResultAnswer)
            }
        }
    
        private fun takePhotoUsingCamera(){
            ImagePicker.with(this).cameraOnly()
                .crop()
                .start(REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA)
        }
    
        // to access the image captured
        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                when (requestCode){
                    REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA -> {
                        selectedPhotoUri = data!!.data
                        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
                        val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
    
                        val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
                        imageButton.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        fun submitForm(userId : String, TestOption: String, ResultOption: String){
    
            ...
    
          
    
            if (imageButton.drawable == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image of your Test result is required!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                imageButton.requestFocus()
            }
    
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for taking the time to answer my question but this method does not work. as stated by Mike M. in the comment above, it will never be null due to its drawable set layout. i have changed my approach to achieve my target outcome.

Answer (score 0):

as stated by Mike M. in the comment above, it will never be null due to its drawable set layout. i have changed my approach to achieve my target outcome.